# Vue: Modify data return depends userAgent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, user-agent

I'm new in VUE, I try to modify the **disabled** value depends the userAgent to show or hide the paymentMethod:

```
data() {
            return {
                paymentMothods: [
                    { name: 'Visa checkout', img: 'visa.png', disabled: false, height: '19', class: 'v-button' },
                    { name: 'PayPal', img: 'paypal.png', disabled: false, height: '18.9', class: '' },
                    { name: 'PhonePE', img: 'phonepe.png', disabled: true, height: '18.9', class: 'phonepe' },
                ]
           }
},
```

If the userAgent is **phonepe-webview** I try to change the value:

```
methods: {
            phopepeMatch: function () {
                let userAgent = navigator.userAgent
                let phonepeMatch = userAgent.match("phonepe-webview")
                if (phonepeMatch === "phonepe-webview"){
                    this.paymentMothods[2].disabled = false
                    return true
                }
                else {
                    return false
                }
            }
},
```

But this doesn´t show the payment method :(

Comment: match is case sensitive - also, how/where is `phopepeMatch` method called? And one more thing, match returns null or an array - so you'd want `if (phonepeMatch && phonepeMatch[0] === "phonepe-webview")`

Comment: Put `console.info(phonepeMatch)` in a line before your `if` statement. What is displayed?

Comment: Spoiler Alert: `.match()` returns an array, not a string. Your function will always return false: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding regarding what `match` returns. In case of a match it returns an array, **not the matched string**. In case of failure it returns `null`. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

You can update your code to fix this:

```
phopepeMatch: function () {
  let userAgent = navigator.userAgent
  let phonepeMatch = userAgent.match("phonepe-webview")
  if (phonepeMatch === null){
    return false
  }
  else {
    this.paymentMothods[2].disabled = false
    return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`.splice()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays).

```
methods: {
        phopepeMatch: function () {
            let userAgent = navigator.userAgent
            let phonepeMatch = userAgent.match("phonepe-webview")
            if (phonepeMatch === "phonepe-webview"){
                // first you need to copy the whole object
                let payment_method = this.paymentMothods[2];
                // next is to modify the property of the object you want to change
                payment_method.disabled = false;
                // finally, replace the old one with the new object
                this.paymentMothods.splice(2, 1, payment_method);
                return true
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        }
```

},

### More information:

In Vue's documentation, under the [**Reactivity in depth**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) section, it states:

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> 1.) When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue
>
> 2.) When you modify the length of the array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

However, Vue does provide a way to do it in which Vue's **Reactivity System** will be able to detect your changes in an array.

**Instead of this:**

```
this.paymentMothods[2].disabled = false
```

**You should do it like this:**

```
let payment_method = this.paymentMothods[2];

payment_method.disabled = false;

this.paymentMothods.splice(2, 1, payment_method);
```

**or like this (using [this.$set()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set)):**

```
let payment_method = this.paymentMothods[2];

payment_method.disabled = false;

this.$set(this.paymentMothods, 2, payment_method);
```